# Skipping comment line from keyboard via stdin

Tags: c++, stream

The requirement is to skip a line beginning from `#` sign.  Basically, we need to treat it as a comment line. The input is given by the user from the keyboard. I will not be reading it from a file. I have a link to the code that i have written so far. In this code, I have used multiple lines to skip a commented line which is in red colored text.

I wanted to know if it could be improved. As in, just one line of code to skip comment line.

Please note: The comment line could be given anywhere from the keyboard.

```
#include
#include
#include
#include

using namespace std;

unsigned long int m;
unsigned long int n;
int res;
unsigned long int i, j, k, ctr, maxIndex;
long int l,la,lb;
string command, key,comment;
string indexS;
long int index, lo=0, hi,mid;
char key1[500];
char keyd[500];
char keym[500];
char data1[10000][500], maskS[10000][500];
char maskey[10000];
char maskSt[10000][500];
char data[10000][500];

void *runner(void *numbers);
void *runnera(void *numbersa);
void *runnerStar(void *numbers);
void *runnerStara(void *numbersa);
int readKey(string s); /* A function that returns 1 when '*' is found and returns 0 if '*' not found in key*/
void checkKey(string str);
void checkIndex(string strInd);
char StoC(string input);
void mErr(string eKey, unsigned long int mCheck);
long int search(char dataS[10000][500], char keyS[500], unsigned long int mS, unsigned long int nS, unsigned long int initial, unsigned long int final);
long int searchStar(char dataSt[10000][500],char keySt[500], unsigned long int mSt, unsigned long int nSt, unsigned long int initialSt, unsigned long int finalSt);

long int searchA(char dataS[10000][500], char keyS[500], unsigned long int mS, unsigned long int nS, unsigned long int initial, unsigned long int final);
long int searchStarA(char dataSt[10000][500],char keySt[500], unsigned long int mSt, unsigned long int nSt, unsigned long int initialSt, unsigned long int finalSt);

/*---Structure for threads--*/
struct arg_struct {
  char numData[5000][500];
  char numKey[500];
  unsigned long int numM;
  unsigned long int numN;
  unsigned long int numLo;
  unsigned long int numMid;
};

struct arg_structa {
  char numaData[5000][500];
  char numaKey[500];
  unsigned long int numaM;
  unsigned long int numaN;
  unsigned long int numaMid;
  unsigned long int numaHi;
};

int main()
{

  cout << "Enter the command:"<< endl;
  cout << "Enter input  of the form:\n";
    cout << "(a) for insert(i) and replace(r) : i \n";
    cout << "(b) for delete(d)                : d \n";
    cout << "(c) for searching(s)             : s \n";

  cin >> command;
  const char *comnta = command.c_str();

  if(*comnta =='#') { /*Skipping comment line part*/
    cin.clear();
    getline(cin,comment);
    cin>>command;
    const char *comntb = command.c_str();

    if(*comntb =='#') { /*Skipping comment line part*/
      cin.clear();
      getline(cin,comment);
      cin>>command;
    }
    const char *comntc = command.c_str();

    if(*comntc =='#') { /*Skipping comment line part*/
      cin.clear();
      getline(cin,comment);
      cin>>command;
    }
  }

  try {
    if(command == "d") {
      cin >> indexS;
      const char *indexComm = indexS.c_str();

      if(*indexComm == '#') { /*Skipping comment line part*/
    cin.clear();
    getline(cin,comment);
    cin>>indexS;
    index = atoi(indexS.c_str());
    const char *indexComma = indexS.c_str();

    if(*indexComma == '#') { /*Skipping comment line part*/
      index = 0;
      cin.clear();
      getline(cin,comment);
      cin>>indexS;
      index = atoi(indexS.c_str());
    }
      }
      checkIndex(indexS);
      index  = atoi(indexS.c_str());
    }

    else if(command =="s") {
      cin >> key;
      const char *keyComm = key.c_str();

      if(*keyComm == '#') { /*Skipping comment line part*/
    cin.clear();
    getline(cin,comment);
    cin>> key;
    const char *keyComma = key.c_str();

    if(*keyComma == '#') { /*Skipping comment line part*/
      cin.clear();
      getline(cin,comment);
      cin>> key;
    }
      }
      checkKey(key);
    }

    else if(command == "i" || command == "r") {
      cin >> indexS;

      const char *indexCommc = indexS.c_str();
      if(*indexCommc == '#') { /*Skipping comment line part*/
    cin.clear();
    getline(cin,comment);
    cin>>indexS;
    index = atoi(indexS.c_str());
    const char *indexCommd = indexS.c_str();

    if(*indexCommd == '#') {
      index = 0;
      cin.clear();
      getline(cin,comment);
      cin>>indexS;
      index = atoi(indexS.c_str());
    }
      }
      checkIndex(indexS);
      index  = atoi(indexS.c_str());
      ctr = index;

      if(maxIndex < ctr)
    maxIndex = ctr;

      cin >> key;
      const char *keyCommb = key.c_str();

      if(*keyCommb == '#') {
    cin.clear();
    getline(cin,comment);
    cin>> key;
    const char *keyCommc = key.c_str();

    if(*keyCommc == '#') {
      cin.clear();
      getline(cin,comment);
      cin>> key;
    }
      }
      checkKey(key);
    }

    else
      throw(command);  
  }

  catch(string err) {
    cout << "The input must be of the form:\n";
    cout << "(a) for insert(i) and replace(r) : i \n";
    cout << "(b) for delete(d)                : d \n";
    cout << "(c) for searching(s)             : s \n";
    exit(0);
  }

  m = key.size();  /* Bit size of each entry of TCAM*/
  n = 10000;                     /*Number of entries in TCAM*/

  /*--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
  int loop = 0;
  for(;;) {
    cout << "Enter input  of the form:\n";
    cout << "(a) for insert(i) and replace(r) : i \n";
    cout << "(b) for delete(d)                : d \n";
    cout << "(c) for searching(s)             : s \n";
    if(loop == 1) {
      cout << "Enter the command:\n";
      if (!(cin >> command))
    break;
      const char *comntd = command.c_str();
      if(*comntd =='#') {
    cin.clear();
    getline(cin,comment);
    cin>>command;
    const char *comntd = command.c_str();

    if(*comntd =='#') {
      cin.clear();
      getline(cin,comment);
      cin>>command;
    }
    const char *comnte = command.c_str();

    if(*comnte =='#') {
      cin.clear();
      getline(cin,comment);
      cin>>command;
    }
      }

      try {
    if(command == "d")
      {
        cin >> indexS;

        const char *indexCommd = indexS.c_str();
        if(*indexCommd == '#') {
          cin.clear();
          getline(cin,comment);
          cin>>indexS;
          index = atoi(indexS.c_str());
          const char *indexComme = indexS.c_str();

          if(*indexComme == '#') {
        index = 0;
        cin.clear();
        getline(cin,comment);
        cin>>indexS;
        index = atoi(indexS.c_str());
          }
        }
        checkIndex(indexS);
        index  = atoi(indexS.c_str());
      }
    else if(command =="s") {
      cin >> key;
      const char *keyCommd = key.c_str();
      if(*keyCommd == '#') {
        cin.clear();
        getline(cin,comment);
        cin>> key;
        const char *keyComme = key.c_str();
        if(*keyComme == '#') {
          cin.clear();
          getline(cin,comment);
          cin>> key;
        }
      }
      checkKey(key);
      mErr(key, m);
    }

    else if(command == "i" || command == "r") {
      cin >> indexS;
      const char *indexCommf = indexS.c_str();

      if(*indexCommf == '#') {
        cin.clear();
        getline(cin,comment);
        cin>>indexS;
        index = atoi(indexS.c_str());
        const char *indexCommg = indexS.c_str();

        if(*indexCommg == '#') {
          index = 0;
          cin.clear();
          getline(cin,comment);
          cin>>indexS;
          index = atoi(indexS.c_str());
        }
      }
      checkIndex(indexS);
      index  = atoi(indexS.c_str());
      ctr = index;

      if(maxIndex < ctr)
        maxIndex = ctr;

      cin >> key;
      const char *keyCommf = key.c_str();
      if(*keyCommf == '#') {
        cin.clear();
        getline(cin,comment);
        cin>> key;
        const char *keyCommg = key.c_str();

        if(*keyCommg == '#') {
          cin.clear();
          getline(cin,comment);
          cin>> key;
        }
      }
      checkKey(key);
      mErr(key, m);
    }  

    else
      throw(command);
      }

      catch(string err)    {
    cout << "The input must be of the form:\n";
    cout << "(a) for insert(i) and replace(r) : i \n";
    cout << "(b) for delete(d)                : d \n";
    cout << "(c) for searching(s)             : s \n";
    exit(0);
      }
    }
      loop =1;
      /*-------------Without '*' bits in the search key i.e res=0-------------------------------*/
      /*-------------------------------Begin searching part of the code------------------------*/

      readKey(key);

      if(command == "s" && res ==0)
    {
      StoC(key); /* returns key1 which is a char type*/

      pthread_t tid, tida;
      pthread_attr_t attr;
      pthread_attr_init(&attr);

      struct arg_struct args;
      struct arg_structa argsa;
      /*----Spliting up the indices of the TCAM for parallelism-----*/
      lo =0;
      hi =  maxIndex;
      mid = (lo+hi)/2;

      /*-----Assigning values to the data structure-------*/
      for(unsigned long int o=lo; o<=mid; o++)
        for(unsigned long int r=0; r           {
        args.numData[o][r] = data[o][r];
        args.numKey[r] = key1[r];

          }
      for(unsigned long int x=mid+1; x<=hi; x++)
        for(unsigned long int u=0; u           {
               argsa.numaData[x][u] = data[x][u];
               argsa.numaKey[u] = key1[u];

          }

        args.numM = m;
        args.numN = n;
        args.numLo = lo;
        args.numMid = mid;

               argsa.numaM = m;
        argsa.numaN = n;
        argsa.numaMid = mid;
        argsa.numaHi = hi;

        /*----Creating 2 threads to be executed------*/
        pthread_create(&tid, &attr, runner, (void *)&args);
             pthread_create(&tida, &attr, runnera, (void *)&argsa); /* thread for second half of data*/

        /*-------Waiting for both the thrads to complete execution-------*/
        pthread_join(tid, NULL);
        pthread_join(tida, NULL);

        /*------Printing ouput values based on lowest index match----------*/
        if(la ==-1 && lb==-1)
          cout<< la <        
        else if(la == -1 && lb >=0)
          cout<< lb <        
        else if(la >= 0 && lb ==-1)
          cout<< la <        
        else if(la>=0 && lb >=0)
          cout<< la <     }


      /*-----------------Search with '*' bits in the search key---------------------------------------------*/

      else if(command == "s" && res==1)
    {
      StoC(key);

      pthread_t thid, thida;
      pthread_attr_t attr;
      pthread_attr_init(&attr);

      struct arg_struct args;
      struct arg_structa argsa;

      lo =0;
      hi =  maxIndex;
      mid = (lo+hi)/2;

      for(unsigned long int o=lo; o<=mid; o++)
        for(unsigned long int r=0; r           {
        args.numData[o][r] = data[o][r];
        args.numKey[r] = key1[r];
          }
      for(unsigned long int x=mid+1; x<=hi; x++)
        for(unsigned long int u=0; u           {
               argsa.numaData[x][u] = data[x][u];
               argsa.numaKey[u] = key1[u];
          }

      args.numM = m;
      args.numN = n;
      args.numLo = lo;
      args.numMid = mid;

      argsa.numaM = m;
      argsa.numaN = n;
      argsa.numaMid = mid;
      argsa.numaHi = hi;

      /*--------creating thread for program-----------------*/
      pthread_create(&thid, &attr, runnerStar, (void *)&args);
      pthread_create(&thida, &attr, runnerStara, (void *)&argsa); /* thread for second half of data*/

      /*------Wait for both the threads to complete execution--------*/
      pthread_join(thid, NULL);
      pthread_join(thida, NULL);

        /*------Printing ouput values based on lowest index match----------*/
        if(la ==-1 && lb==-1)
          cout<< la <

        else if(la == -1 && lb >=0)
          cout<< lb <

        else if(la >= 0 && lb ==-1)
          cout<< la <

        else if(la>=0 && lb >=0)
          cout<< la <
    }

      /*-------------Inserting data at index-- i key 1011-----dataind[n+1][m]-------------------------*/
      else if(command =="i")
    {
      StoC(key);

      if((data[index][0] == '\0')) {
        for(unsigned long int bit=0; bit           data[index][bit] = key1[bit];
      }
      else {
        unsigned long int g = 0;
        for(g=(index+1);g           if(data[g][0] =='\0')
        break;
        }

        if(maxIndex < g)
          maxIndex = g;

        for( unsigned long int e=g; e>index; e--)
          for(unsigned long int biti=0; biti         data[e][biti] = data[e-1][biti];

        for( unsigned long int bit=0; bit           data[index][bit] = key1[bit];
      }
    }
      /*------------- delete index---------------------------*/
      else if(command =="d")
    {  
      i=0;
      for(i=index; i<=maxIndex;i++)
        for(int bitd=0; bitd           data[i][bitd]= data[i+1][bitd];

      if(maxIndex >= index && maxIndex !=0)
        maxIndex = maxIndex-1;
    }

      /*------------- replace index key---------------------------*/

      else if(command == "r")
    {  
      StoC(key);
      for(unsigned long int bitr=0; bitr         data[index][bitr] = key1[bitr];
    }
       cout<<"\n\n\n";
  cout<<<"tcam table="" entries="" without="" star\n";   // line();
  cout<<<"index"<<<"data"<<<"mask"<
  //line();
  for(unsigned long int k=0;k<=10;k++)
    { 
      cout<<<<<
    }
  //line();
  cout<<<

  }

  return 0;
}

/*----------------------Function definitions begin------------------*/
int readKey(string s)
{
  const char *p = s.c_str();
  while (*p != '\0') {
    if (*p == '*') {
      res = 1;
      return(res);
    }
    else {
      res = 0;
    }
    *p++;
  }
  return(res);
}

/*-------------------------------------------------*/
void checkKey(string str)
{
  const char *p = str.c_str();
  try {
    while (*p != '\0') {
      if(*p=='*' || *p=='0' || *p=='1')
    *p++;
      else
    throw(*p);
    }
  }
  catch( char error) {
    cout <<"ERROR: The input key must be in '1', '0', or '*'" << endl;
    exit(0);
  }    
}
/*-------------------------------------------------*/

void checkIndex(string strInd)
{
  const char *ind = strInd.c_str();
  try {
    while (*ind != '\0') {
      if(*ind=='0'|| *ind=='1'|| *ind=='2'|| *ind=='3'|| *ind =='4'|| *ind=='5'|| *ind=='6'|| *ind=='7'|| *ind=='8'|| *ind=='9')
    *ind++;
      else
    throw(*ind);
    }
  }
  catch( char error) {
    cout <<"ERROR: The input index must be a number" << endl;
    exit(0);
  }
}


/*----------------------------------------------------*/
char StoC(string input)
{
  i = 0; 
  const char *p = input.c_str();
  while (*p != '\0')
    {
      key1[i] = *p;
      i++;
      *p++;   
    }
  return(*key1);
}

 /*-----------------ERROR in key length-------------------------*/

void mErr(string eKey, unsigned long int mCheck)
{
  if(eKey.size() != mCheck) {
    cout<< "ERROR: Key size must not vary"<
    exit(0);
  }
}

/*---------------------------Search without * key-----------------*/

long int search(char dataS[10000][500],char keyS[500], unsigned long int mS, unsigned long int nS, unsigned long int initial, unsigned long int final)
{
  /*---------------------Generating mask of the TCAM entries----------------------------*/

  for(unsigned long int i=initial; i<=final; i++)
    for(unsigned long int j=0; j       if(dataS[i][j] == '*')
    maskS[i][j]='0';
      else
    {
      data1[i][j] = dataS[i][j];
      maskS[i][j] = '1';
    }

  bool flag = true;
  for(la=initial; la<=final; la++) {
    flag = true;
    for(unsigned long int k=0;k       if ( maskS[la][k]== '1') {
    if (keyS[k] != data1[la][k])
      {
        flag = false;
      }
      }
    }
    if (flag)
      {
    return(la);
      }
  }
  la = -1;
  return(la); 
}

/*---------------------------Search without * key2-----------------*/
long int searchA(char dataS[10000][500],char keyS[500], unsigned long int mS, unsigned long int nS, unsigned long int initial, unsigned long int final)
{
  /*---------------------Generating mask of the TCAM entries----------------------------*/
  for(unsigned long int u=initial+1; u<=final; u++)
    for(unsigned long int j=0; j       if(dataS[u][j] == '*')
    maskS[u][j]='0';
      else
    {
      data1[u][j] = dataS[u][j];
      maskS[u][j] = '1';
    }       
  bool flaga = true;
  for(lb=initial+1; lb<=final; lb++) {
    flaga = true;
    for(unsigned long int k=0;k       if ( maskS[lb][k]== '1') {
    if (keyS[k] != data1[lb][k]) {
      flaga = false;
    }
      }
    }
    if (flaga)
      {
    return(lb);
      }
  }

  lb = -1;
  return(lb); 

}
/*------------------------------Search with * key-------------------------------------------------------*/
long int searchStar(char dataSt[10000][500],char keySt[500], unsigned long int mSt, unsigned long int nSt, unsigned long int initialSt, unsigned long int finalSt)
{

  for(unsigned long int a=initialSt; a<=finalSt; a++)
    for(unsigned long int b=0; b       if(dataSt[a][b] == '*') maskSt[a][b]='0';
      else
    {
      data1[a][b] = dataSt[a][b];
      maskSt[a][b] = '1';
    }
  for(unsigned long int j=0;j
    {
      if(keySt[j] =='*')
    keym[j] = '0';
      else
    { 
      keyd[j] = keySt[j];
      keym[j] = '1';
    }
    }
  bool flag = true;
  for( la=initialSt; la<=finalSt; la++) {
    flag = true;
    for(unsigned long int k=0;k       if ( maskSt[la][k]== '1' && keym[k]=='1') {
    if (keyd[k] != data1[la][k]  )
      {
        flag = false;
      }
      }
    }
    if (flag)
      {
    return(la);
      }
  }

  la = -1;
  return(la); 
}
/*---------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
/*------------------------------Search with * key-------------------------------------------------------*/
long int searchStarA(char dataSt[10000][500],char keySt[500], unsigned long int mSt, unsigned long int nSt, unsigned long int initialSt, unsigned long int finalSt)
{
  for(unsigned long int a=initialSt+1; a<=finalSt; a++)
    for(unsigned long int b=0; b       if(dataSt[a][b] == '*') maskSt[a][b]='0';
      else
    {
      data1[a][b] = dataSt[a][b];
      maskSt[a][b] = '1';
    }


  for(unsigned long int j=0;j
    {
      if(keySt[j] =='*')
    keym[j] = '0';

      else
    { 
      keyd[j] = keySt[j];
      keym[j] = '1';
    }
    }
  bool flaga = true;
  for( lb=initialSt+1; lb<=finalSt; lb++) {
    flaga = true;
    for(unsigned long int k=0;k       if ( maskSt[la][k]== '1' && keym[k]=='1') {
    if (keyd[k] != data1[la][k]  )
      {
        flaga = false;
      }
      }
    }
    if (flaga)
      {
    return(lb);
      }
  }

  lb = -1;
  return(lb); 
}

/*-----------Thread1 function for searching without star key------------------*/
void *runner(void *numbers)
{
  struct arg_struct *args = (struct arg_struct *)numbers;
  search(args-> numData, args-> numKey, args-> numM, args-> numN, args-> numLo, args-> numMid);
  pthread_exit(0);
}

/*-----------Thread2 function for searching without star key------------------*/
void *runnera(void *numbersa)
{
  struct arg_structa *argsa = (struct arg_structa *)numbersa;
  searchA(argsa-> numaData, argsa-> numaKey, argsa-> numaM, argsa-> numaN, argsa-> numaMid, argsa-> numaHi);
  pthread_exit(0);
  }

/*-----------Thread1 function for searching without star key------------------*/
void *runnerStar(void *numbers)
{
  struct arg_struct *args = (struct arg_struct *)numbers;
  searchStar(args-> numData, args-> numKey, args-> numM, args-> numN, args-> numLo, args-> numMid);
  pthread_exit(0);
}

void *runnerStara(void *numbersa)
{
  struct arg_structa *argsa = (struct arg_structa *)numbersa;
  searchStarA(argsa-> numaData, argsa-> numaKey, argsa-> numaM, argsa-> numaN, argsa-> numaMid, argsa-> numaHi);
  pthread_exit(0);
}
```

Comment: This code is a simple tcam simulation

Comment: Please copy your code _here_ so we may review it... don't link to it.  Edit your post question to include it.

Comment: Added the code..

Answer (score 2):

There is far too much code here for me to review all of it. However, this looks like pure `C` except for `std::string` and some `iostream` usage. I don't know how familiar you are with `C++` as opposed to `C`, but I would write many of these functions very, very differently. In just about every function relating to string manipulation, you first convert it to a C-style string, and then use a lot of old constructs. Much of this can be **greatly** simplified:

```
int readKey(string s) 
{
    //Lots of C string wrangling
}
```

can be a one-liner:

```
bool readKey(const std::string& str)
{
    return str.find('*') != std::string::npos;
}
```

The function signature has changed a bit. Firstly, don't pass `string` by value, pass it by reference to const. Secondly, `string` has a lot of what you're trying to do inbuilt (and for examples later on, if it doesn't, `<algorithm>` probably does).

---

`checkKey` and `checkIndex` do almost the exact same thing - abstract this out into a single function:

```
bool checkValid(const std::string& s, const std::string& allowable, 
                const std::string& error)
{
    bool valid = std::all_of(s.begin(), s.end(), 
                   [&allowable](char c) 
                   { return allowable.find(c) != std::string::npos; });            
    if(!valid) {
        std::cerr << error << "\n";
    }
    return valid;
}
```

Then again `checkKey` and `checkIndex` become one liners:

```
bool checkKey(const std::string& s)
{
    return checkValid(s, "*01", "Error: The input key must be in '1', '0', or '*'");
}

bool checkIndex(const std::string& strInd)
{
    return checkValid(s, "0123456789", "Error: The input key must a number");
}
```

Using `throw` and then `catch` straight after to signal an error looks horrific to me. I'd personally rather return a `bool`, but you could simply make the function `void` and call `exit` again if you really want it to stop.

---

`char StoC(string input)` simply copies `input` into `key1`. Firstly, this is a buffer overflow just waiting to happen - there is absolutely no checking whether the length of `input` will overflow `key1`. Again, more useless `C` string wrangling. Assigning to global variables (ugh). The function name also leaves a lot to be desired. The previous ones could be improved, but after reading the code, I suppose I can at least sort of understand the names. This function name still makes no sense to me.

Further, this doesn't need to be a function. Why even declare `key1` as a `char[]`? Why not have it as a `string` and simply use copy assignment: `key1 = <some string>`?

---

I don't really want to dig into some of the longer functions. The function names need a *lot* of work, for example:

```
void *runner(void *numbers);
void *runnera(void *numbersa);
void *runnerStar(void *numbers);
void *runnerStara(void *numbersa);
```

I can glean absolutely nothing from those function names. The same can be said with regards to the variable names.

Your `main` function is far, far too long - it needs to be broken up into more functions. The formatting is haphazard - perhaps this is a consequence of pasting the code here, but the whitespace is all over the place, making it even harder to read (and it's pretty hard to read to start with!).

I realize you're using `pthreads` which makes things slightly more complicated. However, you can still easily utilize `std::string` and `std::vector` properly. Don't use things like:

```
char data1[10000][500];
```

Use a `std::vector<std::string>` instead. It'll be less wasteful, you won't have to preallocate huge arrays to make sure they're always big enough (and there's never, ever any guarantee of that anyway). Both `std::string` and `std::vector` have C compatible layouts (if you need to pass the underlying array for `std::vector`, it's as simple as passing `&v[0]`).

Basically (and this might sound a bit harsh), if I were given this code and told to maintain it, I would try to figure out exactly what it did. I would then throw everything away and rewrite it all from scratch, because it would probably take me less time than trying to decipher it.

Comment: Yes. Ill b making changes as per your suggestions. Thank you.